# Styling issue with file uploader

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, file-upload

I have a file upload button with a weird styling issue that I can't seem to solve.  the generated HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="uniform-file_upload" class="uploader">
<input id="file_upload" type="file" multiple="multiple" name="file_upload" size="55" style="opacity: 0;">
<span class="filename" style="-moz-user-select: none;">No file selected</span>
<span class="action" style="-moz-user-select: none;">Choose File</span>
</div>
```

And the output is as follows:

[image]

Can you see the little box around the words "Choose file"?  Well, it is very ugly and distracting and I thought it should be easy to get rid of it but I can't do it.

Comment: are you using uploadify?

Comment: no, it's just some random theme that I have used.

Comment: is it possible to create a jsfiddle or share the link to site (if live)?

Comment: it looks like the box is the default file upload button. I think you can hide that button with css and use JS to trigger the pressing of that button to browse for a file

Comment: Apparently the moderators don't want you to see this: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a situation like this, a good debugging trick would be to use the Chrome web browser and try the **Inspect Element** option. Right-click the form button (in your web page) and choose "Inspect Element" (FireFox has something similar, but I prefer the Chrome one)

The Styles information for the button appears on the side panel and you can tweak the styles to get the required effect.

NB: Verify you have selected the correct html tag in the Elements tab section after clicking Inspect Element. Also, element.style {...} is an option in the side panel and it allows you to edit the inline css for the selected html element.